# Lazarus ошибка External: SIGSEGV

Tags: pascal, lazarus

```
unit Unit5;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, ExtCtrls,
  Buttons, StdCtrls;

type
    uk=^O;
    O=object
    data:integer;
    next:uk;
end;

type

{ TForm5 }



TForm5 = class(TForm)
BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
Button1: TButton;
Edit1: TEdit;
Image1: TImage;
Image10: TImage;
Image11: TImage;
Image2: TImage;
Image3: TImage;
Image4: TImage;
Image5: TImage;
Image6: TImage;
Image7: TImage;
Image8: TImage;
Image9: TImage;
procedure BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
procedure closedln(k:integer);
procedure CreateLol(s: string);
procedure CreateStack(first: uk; el: integer);
procedure printi(k,n:integer);
private
{ private declarations }
public
{ public declarations }
end;

var
    Form5: TForm5;
    first, second, third : uk;

implementation
      uses Unit4;

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm5 }

procedure TForm5.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form5.Close;
end;

procedure TForm5.closedln(k:integer);    //удаление карты с формы
begin
   case k of
    1:Image2.Visible:=false;
    2:Image3.Visible:=false;
    3:Image4.Visible:=false;
    4:Image5.Visible:=false;
    5:Image6.Visible:=false;
    6:Image7.Visible:=false;
    7:Image8.Visible:=false;
    8:Image9.Visible:=false;
    9:Image10.Visible:=false;
    10:Image11.Visible:=false;
end;
end;

procedure TForm5.printi(k, n : integer);  //вывод карты в положенном месте
var
  s1:string;
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages();
  s1 := inttostr(n);
  s1 := s1 +'.png';
  //Edit1.Text := 'printi';
  case k of
   1:begin
          Image2.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image2.Visible:=true;
   end;
   2:begin
          Image3.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image3.Visible:=true;
   end;
   3:begin
         Image4.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image4.Visible:=true;
   end;
   4:begin
          Image5.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image5.Visible:=true;
   end;
   5:begin
          Image6.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image6.Visible:=true;
   end;
   6:begin
          Image7.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image7.Visible:=true;
   end;
   7:begin
          Image8.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image8.Visible:=true;
   end;
   8:begin
          Image9.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image9.Visible:=true;
   end;
   9:begin
          Image10.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image10.Visible:=true;
   end;
   10:begin
          Image11.Picture.LoadFromFile(s1);
          Image11.Visible:=true;
   end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm5.CreateLol(s: string);
var
  k, result: integer;
begin
   Application.ProcessMessages();
   k:=0;
   result:=0;
   repeat
     Application.ProcessMessages();
     k+=1;
     if (s[k]='1') and (k+1<=length(s)) and (s[k+1]='0') then
        begin
           CreateStack(first,10);
           k+=1;
           result+=1;
           printi(result,10);
        end
     else
        if (s[k] in ['0'..'9']) then
           begin
                CreateStack(first,StrToInt(s[k]));
                result+=1;
                printi(result,StrToInt(s[k]));
           end;
    Application.ProcessMessages();
  until k>=length(s);
end;

procedure TForm5.CreateStack(first: uk; el: integer);
var
   u: uk;
begin
 Application.ProcessMessages();
 new(u);
 if first = nil then
    begin
         u^.next := nil;
         u^.data := el;
         Edit1.Text := InttoStr(u^.data);
    end
 else
     begin
          u^.data := el;
          u^.next := first;
          Edit1.Text := InttoStr(u^.data);
     end;
 first := u;
end;

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  s: string;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
      closedln(i);
      s := Unit4.s;
      Application.ProcessMessages();
      CreateLol(s);
end;

procedure TForm5.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;



procedure TForm5.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  s: string;
begin
 Image2.Visible:=false;
 Image3.Visible:=false;
 Image4.Visible:=false;
 Image5.Visible:=false;
 Image6.Visible:=false;
 Image7.Visible:=false;
 Image8.Visible:=false;
 Image9.Visible:=false;
 Image10.Visible:=false;
 Image11.Visible:=false;
 for i := 1 to 10 do
 closedln(i);
 s := Unit4.s;
 Edit1.Text := 'ЛОЛ';
 CreateLol(s);
end;



end.
```

Код формы, в которой ошибка.
    s := Unit4.s; 
    Получаем непустую из цифр через пробел строку, тут ошибок нет.

При запуске ошибка External: SIGSEGV.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что есть параметр `k` и откуда он берётся? Проблема, очевидно, либо в параметре, либо в способе его получения получения. Программа пытается его использовать и обращается не к той ячейке памяти.

Comment: @Risto В процедуре CreateLol вызывается процедура printi. Оттуда и берется k.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  k, result: integer;
```

А вот так делать нельзя. Переменная `result` зарезервирована под результат работы функции. И именно она передаётся у вас в `printi`:

```
printi(result,10);
```

Переименуйте вашу переменную и попробуйте снова.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что в result было дело. В другой программе использовал result и все запускалось без проблем.

Comment: @user192091 если вы используете зарезервированные слова, всегда есть вероятность, что компилятор распознает ваш код неверно. Поэтому, чтобы исключить такую вероятность, лучше просто избегать зарезервированных имён. Никаких гарантий, что причиной исключения действительно было имя переменной нет, но это возможно.

Comment: Ошибка не убралась переименовыванием переменной result

Comment: @user192091 дополнил ответ, посмотрите. По идее, если в указанной строке ошибка - программа вообще не должна была скомпилироваться, так что не берусь судить.

Comment: в vare самой формы